# Remove Webview session

Tags: android, session, webview

I want to remove `WebView` session when I am doing logout from my app.
I have tried below code but unable to do remove session.

**My Code :**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
      CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
      CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookies(null);
      CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
} 
else {
    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = 
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(_context);
            cookieSyncMngr.startSync();
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
            cookieSyncMngr.stopSync();
            cookieSyncMngr.sync();
}


wv_common.clearCache(true);
wv_common.clearHistory();
wv_common.destroy();
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.